# Why is there spaces between the four factors?

Tags: r

[image]

Hello everyone, I am a beginner in R.
The vector "workshop" contains four levels: R SAS SPSS and STATA,
and its string is c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
I ran the factor function as the attached screenshot,
and I do not understand why there will be such spaces between the vectors
which were print out? 
Would it matter that way?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: That's just an effect of how R formats the printout. The spaces aren't really in the vector, they're added in the printout to make every element of equal width.

Comment: your factor has only 2 levels "R" and "SAS" (because the original vector has only 1s and 2s). Is that on purpose?

Comment: Hello @JulienMassardier Your question is what I want to ask next, because my professor does the next thing: 
# Recreate it with just the levels it
# curently has.
workshop <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
workshop <- factor(
  workshop,
  levels=c( 1,  2),
  labels=c("R","SAS")
)
Which I hesitated if I can post here to ask why. Since the results seem both the same. Do you feel these two ways have any different effects? Thank you guys~~<3

Comment: @JulienMassardier I think my professor did it on purpose. He said, "added the levels which are not yet used". Hence, I think it is alright. Thank you and Thank you@AkselA

Comment: It wouldn't change anything to the uneven spaces in the printout. You can try by substituting a few 1s and 2s with 3 and 4 in the original workshop vector.

Comment: The two vectors will look the same when printed, and depending on what you will use them for, they might also function the same, but they will still be, under the surface, quite different. If you haven't already, use `str()` and `dput()` to look at the inner structure of the objects you create, you might find it illuminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R's `print` function (which is actually a family of functions, each one specific to a class of object) generally tries to arrange values so that the column headings and the values line up on either the right or left side. This makes it easier for the human reader to keep things "straight". It does this by first calculating the maximum width and then padding the printed output so that there is space between all values. It may also make it easier to read in from a screen scrape using `read.fwf`, but I don't see that as the primary goal. The code that does this is in `print.factor` which can be seen by typing the function name at the console.

```
 fac <- factor( sample(1:10, size=100, repl=TRUE), labels=c(letters[1:9], "really long level")
+ )
 fac
 #---------------
  [1] a                 f                 d                 d                 d                 b                 e                
  [8] f                 e                 c                 g                 d                 g                 d                
 [15] h                 e                 b                 g                 b                 a                 f                
 [22] really long level d                 c                 e                 e                 g                 f                
 [29] c                 f                 g                 h                 i                 g                 e                
 [36] i                 b                 c                 i                 b                 d                 a                
 [43] c                 i                 a                 e                 really long level g                 g                
 [50] d                 b                 f                 c                 e                 really long level f                
 [57] i                 f                 c                 really long level i                 g                 e                
 [64] e                 h                 h                 e                 h                 b                 a                
 [71] i                 g                 g                 really long level h                 i                 i                
 [78] really long level h                 d                 c                 a                 i                 g                
 [85] e                 really long level e                 e                 f                 c                 e                
 [92] b                 really long level g                 d                 a                 h                 d                
 [99] h                 really long level
Levels: a b c d e f g h i really long level
```

So my initial explanation regarding which side they line up on was wrong in this case, although that does apply to how `print.data.frame` operates. The `print.factor`-function (actually `print.default` does the values) lines them up on the left side. `print.data.frame` lines values up on right.